# Пройдет ли такое приложение в App Store?

Tags: ipad, ios, objective-c, appstore, iphone

Местное книжное издательство хочет сделать в апп сторе свой магазин книжек через in-app.
Книжки - это обычный UIPageViewController.

Так вот, пропустят ли такое приложение, если он в чем-то повторяет iBooks?
Или нужно что-то добавить свое? Например, закадровый голос, видео-материалы.

Может у кого-нибудь был подобный опыт?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Утверждать не буду, но судя по всему пройдут, так как имеются аналоги [Link](http://appstudio.org/readers/). Скачайте парочку, посмотрите чем они схожи, что бы в своём приложении добавить то, чего нет в других.